# Hovering to find precise x and y values using shiny in Rstudio

Tags: r, hover, shiny

I am trying to use hovering to find x and y values using shiny in Rstudio. Below is my code:

```
a <- c(4.7, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 4.3, 121.1, 31.6, 39.0, 51.2)
b <- c(19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 24, 24.5, 25)


ui <- basicPage(
  plotOutput("plot1", hover = "plot_hover"),
  verbatimTextOutput("info")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(b, a, 'o')
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    xy_str <- function(e) {
      if(is.null(e)) return("NULL\n")
      paste0("x=", e$x, " y=", e$y, "\n")
    }

    paste0("hover: ", xy_str(input$plot_hover))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

For my data, I want to find the value of b when a = 10. However, when I try to hover to the position where y = 10.000, I cannot seem to get it precisely as it hovers either on 9.79 or 10.26. Is there any way to make it more precise? Thanks!

Comment: I think the main limitation is the plot resolution (your mouse can only select pixels which are then mapped to x / y values), so to get "higher precision" you would have to zoom in. If you just want to make it pan to certain values (eg integers) you could enforce this by rounding.

Comment: I tried zooming in but it doesn't make a difference

Comment: There are better ways to "find the value of b given a" then trying to find the point with your mouse - and R has them all. Why don't you just use an interpolating spline or something?

Comment: The thing with interpolation is that it requires the data to be monotonic increasing. My data has several peaks and troughs.